# Sending a SMS confirming like Viber in Android

Tags: android, sms, gateway, viber

Is it possible to send SMS
confirmation (or any other content)
in your application other than by the
SMS gateway? I mean here to send
mass quantities of messages, and
the purchase of this package is
quite expensive. I know that Viber
uses something like that, and I
would like to implement it at home,
but I do not know if it's possible to
do without large costs. Talking
about Android. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem. I am using an android app ezSMSgateway(www.ezsmsgateway.com/). it can change your android phone into a sms gateway, so the cost will be cheaper, but you still need to pay your sms fee to telco.
I can't think out a way to sent SMS without any cost yet...